# Changed a column into datetime, but got it as string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I changed dtype of a columns into datetime successfully.
However, I got TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'datetime.datetime'.

I reckon it's because the dtype is datetime64[ns, pytz.FixedOffset(540) (not just datetime64). 
But I do not know what to do.

In another notebook, I got it done successfully.
(The notebook I'm using is another person's, but the original data is the same)

```py
pd.to_datetime(data['action_time'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
```

```
0         2019-08-08 11:00:44+09:00
1         2019-08-08 11:00:47+09:00
2         2019-08-08 11:01:04+09:00
3         2019-08-08 11:01:07+09:00
4         2019-08-08 11:01:09+09:00
                     ...           
1123878   2019-08-14 23:59:56+09:00
1123879   2019-08-15 00:00:00+09:00
1123880   2019-08-15 00:00:01+09:00
1123881   2019-08-15 00:00:04+09:00
1123882   2019-08-15 00:00:04+09:00
Name: action_time, Length: 1123883, dtype: datetime64[ns, pytz.FixedOffset(540)]
```

```py
data[(data['action_time'] >= dt.datetime(2019, 8, 8)) & (data['action_time'] <= dt.datetime(2019, 8, 14))]
```

I just want to subtract a certain period.

Comment: Did you assign `pd.to_datetime(data['action_time'], format='%Y-%m-%d')` to another variable or to itself before you printed it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to assign it back for it to work, as `to_datetime` returns a DF if the parsing succeeded, see [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html)

So, something like:

```py
data = pd.to_datetime(data['action_time'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
```